# Difference between a lossy encoder and a noisy channel in Information Theory

Tags: it.information-theory

$S \to X \to Y \to \hat{S}$

$\text{source} \to \text{input} \to \text{output} \to \text{target}$

In information theory introductory books, an encoder is usually defined as a deterministic function $f:\mathcal{A}_\text{S} \to \mathcal{A}_\text{X}$ that converts a symbol from the alphabet of the source into a code (a symbol of the input of the channel). But it is not uncommon to see it defined as a stochastic map p(X|S). The channel is normally denoted as p(Y|X). In practice, is there any difference between an encoder and a channel? They are both transformations after all.

- changed the title to reflect better what I mean.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `In practice, is there any difference between an encoder and a channel?`

Comment: What I mean is that if an encoder is P(X|S) and a channel is P(Y|X) they both represent a stochastic map between 2 random variables. Therefore, it seems to me that you can apply Shannon`s noisy channel to P(X|S)

Comment: How would you define the rate, $R$ between the source and the input??

Comment: as the compression limit of the encoder P(X|S).

Comment: Wouldn't that instead be the capacity??

Comment: lossy compression ( in the case of $P(X|S)$ ) is analogous to channel noise and compression limit analogous to channel capacity which depends on the randomness of $S$.

Comment: Wonderful! That is exactly what I though. I keep seeing Deep Learning papers where they use$Y \to X \to Z \to \hat{Y}$ and call p(Z|X) an encoder... which I agree in the sense that it is a code transformation: encoder - encoder - decoder, all stochastic. So, I guess the difference is that a channel is one that "nature" or something else changes the code, and lossy encoder is when it is a transformation that we acted upon.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked the difference between a lossy encoder and a noisy channel. Which seems to be the same thing but mean different things in their applications.